# Как парсить сайт с js на python

Tags: python

Как парсить сайт, контент на котором прогружается javascript? Кроме selenium.

Comment: читайте про requests

Comment: Смотреть, что делает этот `js` и выполнять самому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно использовать `requests-html`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]